# How Scheme iteration works?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

From [R5RS](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.4) under **4.2.4  Iteration** -

```
(let ((x '(1 3 5 7 9)))
  (do ((x x (cdr x))
       (sum 0 (+ sum (car x))))
      ((null? x) sum)))
```

What is the usage of  - `cdr` and `car` .

And what happens with this `x` in the  lines  -

```
(do ((x x (cdr x))
           (sum 0 (+ sum (car x))))
          ((null? x) sum))
```

Comment: Whilst learning Scheme from the spec might work, I beg you to consider reading a book instead. There are plenty free ones for instance the famous Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- car = first (as in first element of list)
- cdr = rest (as in everything but the first element of list)

The loop adds up the items in the list.

Comment: according to iteration syntax  , can you please explain what is the `<test> <expression>` and `<command>` here  ?

Comment: The first clause inside the do declares local variables x (initialized to the surrounding x & replaced by (cdr x) with each iteration) and sum (initialized to 0 and replaced by sum plus (car x) with each iteration).  Once the first clause in the second clause is true (x is empty), the value of sum is returned.